# Finding an isometry in $\mathbb R^4$ under some conditions.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

This is a follow-up to a previous question of mine that was not fully answered, I tried again my hand at the problem and I think I am close to a solution.

In an affine space with the standard reference point I am  given the line $r$:

$$r = (3,1,-1) + \langle (-1,2,2)\rangle$$ and the plane $$S = (-1,0,3) + \langle(0,1,-1), (2,1,0)\rangle$$

I would like to find a direct isometry that fixes $r$ and maps the plane $S$ in the plane $T$ parallel to $S$ and that passes through the point $(0,1,3)$. In addition I would like to know if such an isometry can fix all points of $r$.

**My attempt**: A direct isometry is a composition of a linear application with orthogonal associated matrix and a translation, my linear application must at all cost map a vector in the spans of the directional components of $r$ and $S$ to a vector that stays in the respective span if I want to preserve direction.

I know that a linear application will have an orthogonal associated matrix if it maps orthonormal basis to orthonormal basis. I know that the vectors in the spans must be mapped to each other and I notice that they are linearly independent.

So to obtain my starting orthonormal basis I apply Gram–Schmidt to the vectors $\{ (-1,2,2),(0,1,-1),(2,1,0)\}$.

I obtain the three orthonormal vectors $B =\{ (0, 1/ \sqrt{2}, -1/ \sqrt{2}), (2 \sqrt{2}/3, \sqrt{2}/6,\sqrt{2}/6),(-1/3, 2/3, 2/3) \}$

I decide to construct my linear application $\phi$ as so:

$$\phi : (0, 1/ \sqrt{2}, -1/ \sqrt{2}) \rightarrow (0, 1/ \sqrt{2}, -1/ \sqrt{2})$$
$$\phi : (2 \sqrt{2}/3, \sqrt{2}/6,\sqrt{2}/6) \rightarrow  (2 \sqrt{2}/3, \sqrt{2}/6,\sqrt{2}/6)$$
$$\phi : (-1/3, 2/3, 2/3) \rightarrow  (-1/3, 2/3, 2/3)$$

Of course the matrix associated with this linear application in the basis $B$ is the identity,  $M_B(\phi) = I$ . this has determinant equal to one so it's a **direct** isometry.

But I have the standard reference so I need the matrix with respect to the standard coordinates, it turns out it is

$$ M_e (\phi) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1/ \sqrt{2} & -1/ \sqrt{2} \\
4/ 3\sqrt{2} & 1/ 3\sqrt{2} & 1/ 3\sqrt{2} \\
-1/3 & 2/3 & 2/3 \end{array} \right) $$

Now I have taken care of direction but I am missing the fact that the point $(-1,0,3)$ of the plane $S$ should map into the point $Q =(0,1,3)$ belonging to $T$ here is where I decide how my translation $t_v$ is made.

The vector of translation will be given by $v = Q - \phi((-1,0,3))$ that is:

$$ v  = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 &  \\
1 &  \\
3 &  \end{array} \right) - \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1/ \sqrt{2} & -1/ \sqrt{2} \\
4/ 3\sqrt{2} & 1/ 3\sqrt{2} & 1/ 3\sqrt{2} \\
-1/3 & 2/3 & 2/3 \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1 &  \\
0 &  \\
3 &  \end{array} \right) $$

The isometry given by $t_v \circ \phi$ Now maps the plane $S$ in the plane $T$ as requested.

But now I have a problem since If I want to also fix the line $r$ I must also have that $v = (3,1,-1) - \phi ((3,1,-1))$ so I have too many conditions on my $v$. How could I solve this?

I guess another way of putting this is: does there exist a direct isometry of $\mathbb R^3$ different from the identity that maps a line in itself without needing a translation?

Comment: Standard notation is $\langle(-1,2,2)\rangle$, not $<(-1,2,2)>$.  I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can't you simply use a translation along the direction of $r$?

Comment: @Aretino it might very well be that I am over-thinking it, but with a simple translation along the direction of $r$ wouldn’t I need an $a$ s.t.  $(-1,0,3) + a(-1,2,2) = (0,1,3)$ and no such $a$ exists?

Comment: Not necessarily: point $P=(1/9,7/9,25/9)$ belongs to plane $S$ and $P+{1\over9}(-1,2,2)=(0,1,3)$.

Comment: @Aretino thanks! how did you find the point?

Comment: Solve $(-1,0,3) + (0,1,-1)s + (2,1,0)t + (−1,2,2)a=(0,1,3)$ for $s$, $t$, $a$.

Comment: @Aretino I was wondering if you had any ideas for the follow up question "can such an isometry fix all points of r?". I am inclined to say no but how could I formalize it?